# Список словарей

Tags: python

Как отсортировать список словарей по значению определенного ключа, не используя циклы?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

используя функцию sorted

```
sorted(список_словарей, key=lambda x: x['ваш_ключ'])
```

пример:

```
lod = [{'k': 1, 'v': 2}, {'k': 4, 'v': 5}, {'k': 3, 'v': 4}, {'k': 2, 'v': 3}]
print sorted(lod, key=lambda x: x['k'])
```